# Designing a home screen for a mobile app

Tags: android, screen-real-estate

I'd like to show the current day's load-shedding schedule on the home screen, but the design I have looks too empty to me. Any suggestions for things I can add to the screen ?

[image: Home Screen: "good afternoon", shows the times for today and yesterday in cards underneath]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is: Do a benchmarking
Open most famous schedule apps and see how they solve the problem,write positives and negatives points and each app, and try to apply in yours.

Before start the devolpment try to a prototype to.

Answer (score 0):

**Define the jobs that the app needs to do.** Apart from looking at a simple load-shedding schedule, it looks like there is a full schedule, and something that needs to be searched. What else is the user coming to the app to do? Do they need a whole tab for searching, or can you add a search widget on the home screen?

If the app isn't very information-rich, you could probably spread out the scheduling times to fill up the screen. Weather apps and clock apps are pretty creative at making a small amount of information fill a larger view. Perhaps there are some designs that you can borrow inspiration from.

[image: Simple weather app designs]

[image: Simple clock app designs]